# NativeScript - Android only plugin

Tags: nativescript

I am trying to compile my NativeScript App for IOS, however one of the plugins I am using seems to have an issue. It is not a critical element, so as a quick fix I was thinking maybe I can just exclude that plugin for the IOS version. Does anybody know if this is possible?

It works fine with Android.

Comment: You may still keep your plugin but just don't access it in iOS with a simple if condition.

Comment: You can wrap Android and iOS code separately by using platform-specific files. You can change the file name to filename.android.ts and webpack will wrap it only for Android. You may need to create a corresponding filename.ios.ts that includes iOS code. To consume this file, import it using 'import { SomeClass } from "path/to/folder/filename";' without .android or .ios or .ts extensions. You may also need to create a definitions file filename.d.ts and put shared code inside filename.common.ts file. Plugin structure: https://docs.nativescript.org/plugins/building-plugins#step-3-write-your-plugin

Comment: To test out the theory, I comment out the code while leaving the plugin. Andriod doesn't mind, IOS did and still failed to compile. You need to remove the plugin completely.
I guess, going on @MickMorely idea, I should fork the plugin, strip out all the IOS code (I would like to fix it, but I don't have a mac). Then I could put in the if contion mentioned above

Comment: If the iOS code is buggy, then your idea of forking and stripping out iOS code is a good workaround.